# Class property defined but reports "Property does not exists on type xxx"

Tags: typescript

I made a class with TypeScript:

```
export class Vector3 {
    x: number;
    y: number;
    z: number;

    constructor(x, y, z) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }
}
```

And then create an instance of Vector3 class:

```
import { Vector3 } from './engine';
var myVector: Vector3 = new Vector3(1, 2, 3);
```

But when I compile the script, it saids:

```
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/engine.ts:5:14 - error TS2339: Property 'x' does not exist on type 'Vector3'.

5         this.x = x;
               ~
src/engine.ts:6:14 - error TS2339: Property 'y' does not exist on type 'Vector3'.

6         this.y = y;
               ~
src/engine.ts:7:14 - error TS2339: Property 'z' does not exist on type 'Vector3'.

7         this.z = z;
               ~

    at createTSError (/Users/rico345100/Desktop/development/test/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:421:12)
    at reportTSError (/Users/rico345100/Desktop/development/test/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:425:19)
    at getOutput (/Users/rico345100/Desktop/development/test/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:530:36)
    at Object.compile (/Users/rico345100/Desktop/development/test/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:735:32)
    at Module.m._compile (/Users/rico345100/Desktop/development/test/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:814:43)
    at Module.m._compile (/Users/rico345100/Desktop/development/test/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:814:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)
    at require.extensions.<computed> (/Users/rico345100/Desktop/development/test/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:817:12)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (/Users/rico345100/Desktop/development/test/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:817:12)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)
```

I have no idea why this happens. I can clearly see there are x/y/z in Vector3 class definition, but why ts compiler give that errors?

Comment: Playground says there is no issue - https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4DVgJtAZjgG8BYAKDirhAC44A7AVwFsAjYKAbgurgE96zdpx6VqALyGsO3Cr2oIIDNDChM80ABR1hsgDQDpIqIamMZnAJQkFfKjAAWASzQA6EHAC8NMfepOrm783gJ+-nCB7hKhEuFUAL4UCUA

Comment: @MaciejSikora Nah, you are right, Seems like it's ts-node related. Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing, but I think your import statement `import { Vector3 } from './engine';` might be wrong. The class name `Vector3` is quite popular and your IDE may have just imported the wrong class implementation.